# How to create new system service by ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

I have created a script to start/stop my application. Now I want to add it as a centos system service. First I created a task to create a link from my script to /etc/init.d/service_name as below.

```
---

- name: create startup link
  file: src={{ cooltoo_service_script }} dest={{ cooltoo_service_init }} state=link
```

After create the service, I want to add it to system service. The command used to do that is "chkconfig --add service_name". I wonder whether there is a ansible module to do that instead of hardcoded the command in ansible-playbook file. I have looked at this page http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html but it only shows how to manage a service not create a new one.

Comment: It would help to specify the CentOS version, since CentOS 6 uses sysvinit while CentOS 7 uses systemd.  sysvinit compatible init scripts can't always be activated by Ansible's `service` module (or the `systemd` module added in Ansible 2.2), depending on how the Linux distribution configures systemd.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The 'service' module supports an 'enabled' argument.

Here's an example part of a playbook, which I will freely admit does look like a newbie attempt. This assumes RHEL/CentOS 6.x, which uses SysV, not systemd.

```
  - name: install rhel sysv supervisord init script
    copy: src=etc/rc.d/init.d/supervisord dest=/etc/rc.d/init.d/supervisord owner=root group=root mode=0755

  - name: install rhel sysv supervisord sysconfig
    copy: src=etc/sysconfig/supervisord dest=/etc/sysconfig/supervisord owner=root group=root mode=0640

  - name: enable sysv supervisord service
    service: name=supervisord enabled=yes

  - name: start supervisord
    service: name=supervisord state=started
```

**IMPORTANT** A lot of custom init scripts WILL FAIL with Ansible and SysV init; the reason being that the 'status' option (service supervisord status) needs to a return an LSB-compliant return code. Otherwise, Ansible will not know if a service is up or down, and idempotency will fail (restart will still work because that is unconditional)

Here's part of a script, which I've just rewritten to make use of the 'status' function within /etc/init.d/functions (you'll notice this same pattern in other Red Hat provided init-scripts in /etc/init.d/

```
status)
    /usr/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS status
    status -p $PIDFILE supervisord
    # The 'status' option should return one of the LSB-defined return-codes,
    # in particular, return-code 3 should mean that the service is not
    # currently running. This is particularly important for Ansible's 'service'
    # module, as without this behaviour it won't know if a service is up or down.
    RETVAL=$?
    ;;
```

Reference: http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html

> If the status action is requested, the init script will return the
>   following exit status codes.
>
> 0 program is running or service is OK 1   program is dead and /var/run
>   pid file exists 2 program is dead and /var/lock lock file exists
>   3 program is not running 4    program or service status is unknown
>   5-99  reserved for future LSB use 100-149 reserved for distribution use
>   150-199   reserved for application use 200-254    reserved

Answer (score 62):

The below code snippet will create Service in CentOS 7.

### Code

#### Tasks

/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: TeamCity | Create environment file
  template: src=teamcity.env.j2 dest=/etc/sysconfig/teamcity
- name: TeamCity | Create Unit file
  template: src=teamcity.service.j2 dest=/lib/systemd/system/teamcity.service mode=644
  notify:
    - reload systemctl
- name: TeamCity | Start teamcity
  service: name=teamcity.service state=started enabled=yes
```

#### Templates

/templates/teamcity.service.j2

```
[Unit]
Description=JetBrains TeamCity
Requires=network.target
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/teamcity
ExecStart={{teamcity.installation_path}}/bin/teamcity-server.sh start
ExecStop={{teamcity.installation_path}}/bin/teamcity-server.sh stop
User=teamcity
PIDFile={{teamcity.installation_path}}/teamcity.pid
Environment="TEAMCITY_PID_FILE_PATH={{teamcity.installation_path}}/teamcity.pid"
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

\templates\teamcity.env.j2

```
TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH="{{ teamcity.data_path }}"
```

#### Handlers

\handlers\main.yml

```
- name: reload systemctl
  command: systemctl daemon-reload
```

### Reference :

- Ansible playbook structure: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html
- SystemCtl: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Comment: Just nitpicking, but according to the ArchLinux Wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Writing_unit_files) `/etc/systemd/system/` should be used for "units installed by the system administrator". Instead of `(/usr)/lib/systemd/system/`

Comment: Might want to flush handlers before the last task otherwise the daemon reload won't take place until after the role attempts to start the new service

Comment: Modern way to do daemon-reload would be using the systemd module instead of command:
- name: Reload systemctl
  ansible.builtin.systemd:
    daemon_reload: true

Answer (score 6):

Indeed the `service` module only manages already registered services as you have figured out. To my knowledge there is no module to register a service.

Are you aware this step can be skipped with [some modifications](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html#boot.script) to your init.d script? If the script follows those rules you can just use the `service` module to enable/start the service.

Comment: I already have such script to start/stop the service. All I have to do is to register it as a system service. It seems that I have to manually call the shell command to register the service.

Answer (score 4):

For RedHat/CentOS 7 (using systemd/`systemctl`), the equivalent of `chkconfig --add ${SERVICE_NAME}` is `systemctl daemon-reload` [[via fedoraproject.org](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SysVinit_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet)].

Then, using the `systemd` module of Ansible 2.2 or greater, you may start a service with a preceding `systemctl daemon-reload` like so [[via docs.ansible.com](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/systemd_module.html)]:

```
# Example action to restart service cron on centos, in all cases, also issue daemon-reload to pick up config changes
- systemd:
    state: restarted
    daemon_reload: yes
    name: crond
```

Based on my experience, the `daemon_reload` parameter can also be used within the generic `service` module as well, although it isn't documented, and might fail on non-systemd systems:

```
- service:
    state: restarted
    daemon_reload: yes
    name: crond
```